# Ajax call on document load not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hello I want to do an ajax call when a document is loaded. here is the code

```
  script(src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js')  
  script.
      $.ajax({ url: '/labeling/page_refresh', 
              type: 'GET', 
              success: function(data){ console.log(data) }, 
              error: function(error) { console.log(error)} 
              });
```

this is the server side

```
router.get('/labeling/page_refresh', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log("refreshed!")
  db_label.findLabels((err, labels) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.sendStatus(500)
    }
    res.send(labels)
  })
})
```

labels console.logs this

```
[ { _id: 5a73e852316509492f5e0067, label: 'moo: 00:00:00' },
  { _id: 5a73e85a316509492f5e0068, label: 'poo: 00:00:00' } ]
```

client side

```
  h4(class='div-class' id='labels')
```

I am getting back no errors but the data is my own pug file in html format!

Comment: Do you receive response in the "data" during the get ajax call?

Comment: What does the data look like? Is it JSON? If so, I recommend `$.getJSON` instead

Comment: can you please check the network and console window in developer's window

Comment: console.log(data);

Comment: Also, your AJAX call has no error handler so how do you know there's no errors?

Comment: Console.log(data) brings back prints out the whole pug file, here is the pastebin https://pastebin.com/UYnA4Q4M

Comment: Sounds like your backend isn't working correctly then

Comment: There is no error method in your http request.

Comment: After adding the error method this was console logged VM190936 jquery.js:3827 Uncaught TypeError: (s.dataType || "*").toLowerCase is not a function
    at Function.ajax (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js:9046:39)
    at Function.jQuery.(anonymous function) [as get] (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js:9355:17)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/labeling/bupr:2:3)
    at mightThrow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

   $.get( "/labeling/refresh", function( data ){ 
      // success callback
      console.log(data);
   }, function (error){
      //error callback
      console.log(error);
   }); 

});
```

Comment: Thank you this came back with an error message VM190936 jquery.js:3827 Uncaught TypeError: (s.dataType || "*").toLowerCase is not a function
    at Function.ajax (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js:9046:39)
    at Function.jQuery.(anonymous function) [as get] (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js:9355:17)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/labeling/bupr:2:3)
    at mightThrow (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js:3534:29)
    at process

Comment: Debug in chrome and see where you getting this error. Is it in error call back or before execution of get request?

Comment: Thank @Khurshi Ansari your answer lead me to solve my problem, a routing conflict caused the issue